# how to search a JSONArray inside the JSONObject in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a JSONObject which inturn contains two JSONObjects ( key is rows_map and columns_map)

```
    {
        "rows_map":{
        "3":["Test","Test","Test","Test","Test",null,null,null,null,null,"2011-10-07 15:47:56.0",null,null],
        "2":["test","","","","",null,null,null,"123456789","123456789.user","2011-10-07 12:49:49.0",null,null]
    },
        "columns_map":{
columns_map":"fld1","fld2","fld3","fld4","fld5","Latitude","Longitude","Altitude","Mobile Number","Name","Time","Message","Advertisment"]
        }
    }
```

In rows_map 3 and 2 are record numbers. 
Each record is related to columns in columns_map.
I want to get records list based on mobile number column
for eg: recordslist of mobilenumber equal to 123456789

How can i do this.

Comment: That looks like javascript and not java.

Comment: @awm It is json file which i want to read in java and feed to the datatable

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you're trying to read a json using java, you should be parsing it as an object rather than via syntax.  Take a look at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: I am using org.json library. what i wanted is, I wanted to filter/search the JSON based on some conditions. i doesnot wanted to loop through the whole JSON in the file (atleast by myself) and filter it out.

Comment: It's not a database, it's a flat file that is being passed in, you have to search it one record at a time.

Comment: i were loading the file content to a JSONObject. Which i needed to filter.

Comment: That filter goes through each record.  If you're trying to save time it's the same thing.  You have to reduce it before you load the json.  It's simple really, use a PHP script to read the original json parse it and then call that php script to create you a new filtered json so that the browser doesn't have to work.